# Extra fields not in cleaned data of Django Modelform

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a `ModelForm` with some extra fields. I have the `clean()` function of this form overwritten but can't access these extra fields in the `cleaned_data`. When validating the form below, on the second last line `data.get('startDate')` returns `None` as it did not find `startDate` in the cleaned data.

```
## Model ##

class Reservation(models.Model):
    groupName = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    email = models.EmailField()
    comments = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)


## Form ###

class ReservationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    startDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    endDate = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)

    class Meta:
        model = Reservation
        fields = [
            'groupName',
            'email',
            'startDate',
            'endDate',
            'comments'
        ]




    def clean_startDate(self):
        data = self.cleaned_data['startDate']
        if data < datetime.date.today():
            raise forms.ValidationError('Pick a date in the future')
        return data

    def clean(self):
        data = super().clean()

        if data.get('startDate') > data.get('endDate')
            raise forms.ValidationError('End date must be after start date.')
```

Comment: Your `clean_startDate` returns the value of endDate.

Comment: When you debug inside `clean_startDate()` is `data == None`?

Comment: @c6754, no, clean_startDate() works as expected.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, That was a copy-paste error!

Answer (score 0):

The way I was testing this, startDate defaults to the first of january of this year. This means clean_startDate(self) would raise the ValidationError and will not return the data (startDate). Because all the clean_fieldname() methods are called before clean(), startDate will not have a 'cleaned value' in cleaned_data in the clean() function.